# Laravel notification does not send event to Pusher

Tags: push-notification, laravel-8, pusher, laravel-livewire

In this little chat application that I have, users should also receive a notification in the application. My problem is that, while the chat messages are sent through, the notifications are not.

I am using **Laravel 8**, **pusher-php-server 6.1** and **Livewire** for the interface.

In the Livewire controller behind the chat component I do this:

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\ChatMessage;
use App\Jobs\ProcessMailMessage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Livewire\Component;

class Chat extends Component
{
    public $user1;
    public $user2;
    public $channel;
    public $message;
    public $messages = [];

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->user1 = Auth::user();
        $this->user2 = User::where('id', 2)->first();
        $this->channel = "channel-" . $this->user1->id . '-' . $this->user2->id;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.chat');
    }

    public function getListeners()
    {
        return [
            "echo:{$this->channel},ChatMessageSent" => 'notifyNewMessage'
        ];
    }

    public function notifyNewMessage($message)
    {
        // the UI is updated when the message is received
        $this->messages[] = $message;
    }

    public function send()
    {
        $chatMessage = new ChatMessage([
            'message' => $this->message,
            'sender' => $user1->name
        ]);

        $chatMessage->save();

        // this is where I send the message
        broadcast(new \App\Events\ChatMessageSent($this->user1, $this->channel, $this->message))->toOthers();

        // this is where I try to send a notification
        ProcessMailMessage::dispatchAfterResponse($this->user2, $this->message);
    }
}
```

I have a job that is responsible of sending notifications based on some conditions and it looks like this:

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Models\ChatMessage;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\Middleware\RateLimited;

class ProcessMailMessage implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * The user instance.
     *
     * @var \App\Models\User
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * The message.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $message;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($user, $message)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        // send a mail only if the last message was sent more than 10 minutes ago
        $date = new \DateTime;
        $date->modify('-10 minutes');
        $formatted_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $delivery_channels = [ 'broadcast' ];

        if (ChatMessage::where('created_at', '>=', $formatted_date)->count() == 0) {
            $delivery_channels[] = 'mail';
        }

        // send the notification now
        $this->user->notify(new \App\Notifications\MessageReceived(
            $delivery_channels,
            $this->message,
            $this->user->name)
        );
    }
}
```

Now, the code that is supposed to send the notification

```
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\BroadcastMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class MessageReceived extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    public $message;
    public $sender;
    protected $delivery_channels = [ 'broadcast' ];

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($delivery_channels, $message, $sender)
    {
        $this->delivery_channels = $delivery_channels;
        $this->sender = $sender;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return $this->delivery_channels;
    }

    /**
     * Get the broadcastable representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return BroadcastMessage
     */
    public function toBroadcast($notifiable)
    {
        return new BroadcastMessage([
            'message' => $this->message,
            'sender' => $this->sender
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the type of the notification being broadcast.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function broadcastType()
    {
        return 'broadcast.message';
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)->subject('New message notification')->view(
            'mail.html.chat-message'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'message' => $this->message,
        ];
    }
}
```

This part is supposed to send both an e-mail and an in-app notification. The e-mail is sent when it has to but the notification is not.

I have another Livewire component that should receive the notification about a new message sent and its controller is this:

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Livewire\Component;

class ChatNotification extends Component
{
    public $newNotifications= 0;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.chat-notifications');
    }

    public function getListeners()
    {
        return [
            "echo-private:App.User." . Auth::user()->id . ",MessageReceived" => 'notifyNewMessage'
        ];
    }

    public function notifyNewMessage($message)
    {
        $this->newNotifications++;
    }
}
```

I can see in the Pusher console that there's a subscription to a private channel called `private-App.User.1` for the notification but that's it.

To the *User* model I added this method:

```
/**
 * The channels the user receives notification broadcasts on.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function receivesBroadcastNotificationsOn()
{
    return 'users.' . $this->id;
}
```

and I also have this part in *channels.php*

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

I don' get any 403 error in the browser. I send a message, it gets through Pusher to the other side, I get the mail notification but not the in-app notification that is supposed to go through the private chat, though I can see that there's a subscription to the channel in Pusher.

I also tried catching it with **Echo** like this

```
Echo.private('App.User.' + userId)
.notification((notification) => {
    console.log(notification);
});
```

but I don't get anything

Comment: what about the failed job messages? are you running queue:work command?

Comment: I did and I see this in the laravel.log file: `local.ERROR: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://api-eu.pusher.com/apps/1185263/events?` I have the cacert.pem file configure in PHP